# Subview Gesture recognition issues while on scaling/scrolling view that is not at 1:1

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIScrollView that on it I have also created Gesture Recognizers. Tap, Double Tap, two finger tap, etc. On the Scroll View I create several other UIViews. Think of each of these views as Drawing objects. Circle, Squares, buttons, images, etc. Each of the Subviews I can pan, rotate, tap, etc and they all work for the most part.

If the Scaling Scroll View is not at 100% (1-1) then panning the subviews gets a bit sketchy. you can always tap them to get them to Highlight, though panning, rotation, etc is iffy. Typically if I try to pan a selected subview, it pans the scroll view. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. Set the zoom to 100%, or turn off the Scrolling (set scale to the same min/max), I can do what Is expected.

Any Suggestions on where to start troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% why this works, but this is the code that made the issue disappear.  I had to Subclass UIScrollView, override `(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view` and return NO if the view was anything but the `UIView` class for the `UIScrollView.View`

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view { 
    BOOL returnVal =  NO;

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[IoScreenEditorContentView class]]) {
        returnVal = [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:view];
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```